# Segmentatio fault: 11 - Simple linked list c

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm writing a code to get integers from the user and save them in a simple linked list until the numbers are -1 and -1. My problem is: When my list has more than 1 number, the program runs perfectly, but when it enter just one combination of numbers (1, for example) and then -1, I get a segmentation fault. Can anyone help me?

Comment: English variable names and strings would be helpful. Also please show us the terminal output with given input.

Answer (score 1):

Read your warnings:

[image]

it is clear that if you exit in the first case your pointer isn't any good.

Comment: He says the problem happens when he enters `-1 -1` the second time, not the first time.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Grady answer, there's another fatal issue here in `buscaEaddItem`:

```
novo->RA=numRA;
novo->CodTopico=numCOD;
if(curr1==NULL) return novo;

else{
    curr1->next=novo;
    novo->next=NULL;
}
```

if `curr1==NULL`, then `novo->next` isn't set to `NULL`, so it's *undefined behaviour*. You have to set it in both cases, not only in the `else` part.